# Angle between two projected vectors in python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, point-clouds

I'm working on cylinder fitting in point clouds using Python based on [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0097849314001150). I'm stuck at [equation 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuIMz.png). It's about the calculation of an angle between two projected vectors.

Here's my implementation including an example:

```
import numpy as np

p1 = np.asarray([ -6.08021653,  17.9136792 , -14.31057707])
n1 = np.asarray([ -7.05317241,  18.06131922, -14.13292778])
pStar = np.asarray([  5.38806237,  32.68094222, -28.9836691 ])
a = np.asarray([-0.97062874,  0.22803407,  0.07668319])

def getDeltaNormal(pointnormal, pStar, a):
    pi = pointnormal[0:3] #Split Points
    ni = pointnormal[3:] #Split Normals

    diffPPStar = np.subtract(pi,pStar)
    fraq1 = np.cos(np.dot(np.subtract(diffPPStar, np.dot(np.dot(diffPPStar, a), a)), ni))
    fraq2 = np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(diffPPStar, np.dot(np.dot(diffPPStar, a), a)))
    return fraq1 / fraq2

pn = np.hstack((p1, n1))
getDeltaNormal(pn, pStar, a)
```

The result I get with my example values is -0.042 rad (approx.). Based on 3D reconstruction, I expect approx. 2.92 rad.

Any idea where my bug is?

Comment: What were the results of your own debugging attempts? At which point exactly does the program do something you do not understand?

Comment: Why are you dividing the array into two parts? what are pi and his? You have to clarify all these since your problem might transcend what SO is about

Answer (score 0):

I get about 2.3.

I think there might be some problem with the equation. Typically,

||a| . ||b|| . cos(t) = a . b

So,

t = arccos( (a.b)/(||a| . ||b||) )

I am not sure you you can get an angle after you apply a cosine, unless you are not supposed to get an angle.

```
p1_m_p = p1 - pStar
pDota = pStar.dot( a )

num = (p1_m_p - pDota*a).dot( n1 )
den = np.linalg.norm(p1_m_p - pDota*a) * np.linalg.norm( n1 )
result = np.arccos( num/den )
result
```